# Int the following code : Drawer is opening on every screen how can i restrit that I have also used 'locked-closed' function and etc but not working

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

I'm relatively new to React Native and have been working on a project that involves Tab Drawer and Stack Navigators. However, I've been struggling for the past 5 days to find a solution to a specific problem.

I want to restrict the Drawer Navigator from being accessible on certain screens, such as the Login and Onboarding screens. Despite my efforts, I haven't been able to implement this successfully.

Below a brief overview of my navigation setup:

I've tried [locked-open etc functions], but none seem to be working as expected. The Drawer Navigator remains accessible on screens where I want to restrict it.

As a beginner in React Native, I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this. If you've encountered a similar issue or have insights into handling navigation restrictions based on certain screens, please share your expertise.

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
import React from "react";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import Notification_Screen from "../Drawer Screen/Notification/Notification";
import Setting_Screen from "../Drawer Screen/Settings/Setting";
import Profile_Screen from "../Drawer Screen/Profile/Profile";
import Ionicons from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import LocalDonorHome from "../../Local Donor Screens/local_donor_home";
import Make_Donation from "../../Local Donor Screens/Make Donation/Make_donation";
import Food from "../../Local Donor Screens/Make Donation/Food/food";
import Leftover from "../../../Local_Donor/Local Donor Screens/Make Donation/leftovers/leftovers";
import Medecine from "../../../Local_Donor/Local Donor Screens/Make Donation/Medecine/medicine";
import Header from "../../../component/Header";
import Cart from "../../../component/cart";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import Donation_Requtests from "../../Local Donor Screens/Donation_requests";
import Signup_Screen from "../../../SignUp_Screen/signup_screen";
import Login_Screen from "../../../Login_Screen/login_screen";
import Custom_Drawer from "./custom_drawer";
import EditNameScreen from "../Drawer Screen/Settings/Name/Name";
import EditEmailScreen from "../Drawer Screen/Settings/Email/Email";
import EditPasswordScreen from "../Drawer Screen/Settings/Password/Password";
import EditPhone_NumberScreen from "../Drawer Screen/Settings/Phone_Number/Phone_Number";
import Camera_Vision1 from "../../Local Donor Screens/Make Donation/Camra/Camra1";
import Camera_Vision2 from "../../Local Donor Screens/Make Donation/Camra/Camra2";
import Camera_Vision3 from "../../Local Donor Screens/Make Donation/Camra/Camra3";
import OnBording from "../../../OnBording/onbording";
import Recover_Screen from "../../Recover/recover";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const MyTabs = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: "#00a86b",
        inactiveTintColor: "black",
        tabBarStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#F0F4F3",
          position: "relative",
          borderTopWidth: 0,
        },
        tabBarLabelStyle: {
          fontSize: 15,
          fontWeight: "bold",
        },
        tabBarItemStyle: {
          paddingVertical: 2,
          paddingHorizontal: 20,
        },
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={LocalDonorHome}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarIcon: () => (
            <Ionicons name="home-outline" size={25} color={"#00a86b"} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Requests"
        component={Donation_Requtests}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarIcon: () => (
            <Ionicons name="water-outline" size={25} color={"#00a86b"} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const Donor_Nav = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="On Bording"
        component={OnBording}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Login"
        component={Login_Screen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Recover Screen"
        component={Recover_Screen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Sign Up"
        component={Signup_Screen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Donor Home"
        component={MyTabs}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Make Donation"
        component={Make_Donation}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Food"
        component={Food}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Leftover"
        component={Leftover}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Medicine"
        component={Medecine}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Header"
        component={Header}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="My Cart"
        component={Cart}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Setting_Screen"
        component={Setting_Screen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Edit Name"
        component={EditNameScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Edit Email"
        component={EditEmailScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Edit Password"
        component={EditPasswordScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Edit Number"
        component={EditPhone_NumberScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Camra1"
        component={Camera_Vision1}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Camra2"
        component={Camera_Vision2}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Camra3"
        component={Camera_Vision3}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Drawer"
        component={AppNavigator}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const AppNavigator = () => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Drawer.Navigator
      drawerContent={(props) => <Custom_Drawer {...props} />}
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        drawerLabelStyle: {
          marginLeft: -20,
          fontFamily: "Roboto-Medium",
          fontSize: 15,
        },
        drawerActiveBackgroundColor: "#8FE1D7",
        drawerActiveTintColor: "white",
        drawerInactiveTintColor: "#8FE1D7",
      }}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Donor_Nav}
        options={{
          drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Ionicons name="home-outline" size={22} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={Setting_Screen}
        options={({ navigation }) => ({
          drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Ionicons name="settings" size={22} color={color} />
          ),
          onPress: () => {
            navigation.navigate("Donor Home", { screen: "Setting_Screen" });
          },
        })}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Notification"
        component={Notification_Screen}
        options={{
          drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Ionicons name="notifications" size={22} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={Profile_Screen}
        options={{
          drawerIcon: ({ color }) => (
            <Ionicons name="person" size={22} color={color} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);

export default AppNavigator;
```